# How to change color of certain area in page with java script?

Tags: javascript, css, colors, bookmarklet

I have come across "bookmarklets" and found out I can change background color of any page. What I tried and failed was changing of some particular area. I have taken screenshot of debugger in opera. The color I want to change is highlighted on the right side. I hope this screen is sufficient to generate bookmarklet script to past in the address bar.

I want that color to be white.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYgcX.jpg

Could you please help me generating the bookmarklet code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stackoverflow has a rule that you have to first post your own work and then we will try to help you out, we can't help you out if you just post a screenshot.
Anyways this is how its done with javascript.

```
var element  = document.getElementById('ln');
element.style.backgroundColor = "white";
```

I hope you will be careful next time and will post your own work before asking for help.

Comment: Thank you for warning. I have shaped it as final form: 

javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('ln').style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";})()

Comment: You can implement that code by pasting it in the browser's console, you dont necrssarily have to past it in the address bar.To paste it in the broswer's console, for firefox: press F12 and select console.For chrome: press Control -Shift-J.

Comment: I use Opera. Thank you for shortcuts of Chrome and Firefox.